# How can I know if bytes have not been written by the ChannelWriter?

Tags: sockets, netty

After I call the ChannelWriter.wite() method to send a message, it returns me a ChannelFuture. If the receiving end on the other side has disabled read in epoll_wait, I think the socket write is supposed to be partially complete since zero bytes are supposed to be written. I thought of using the returned  ChannelFuture, but  isSuccess() returns true.
How do I know if the ChannelWriter.write() was only partially complete or zero bytes written?

Answer (score 1):

It will only notify the future once the whole bytes are even written or if the write failed.